# Removing escape characters after Marshalling

Tags: json, go, marshalling

In the above code I am trying to convert my key to byte array via Marshal. Although I am successful doing it, when I see the Marshalled string, I am seeing `\` escape character before my json keys. 
Can you please help me remove that?

```
 func GetBytes(key interface{}) ([]byte, error) {

    b, err := json.Marshal(key)
    if err != nil {
            return nil, err
    }

    log.Println("%%%%%%%%%%")
    log.Printf("%+v\n", key)
    log.Println("##########")
    log.Println(string(b));

    return b, nil
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
%%%%%%%%%%
{"entityId":5010740929,"eventTime":1542706233458}
##########
"{\"entityId\":5010740929,\"eventTime\":1542706233458}"
```

Comment: is your `key` is string?

Comment: its an type interface {}

Comment: Do pass a string to GetBytes(key)?

Comment: My producer is passing me this interface. I cannot pass it as a string.

Comment: _If_ `json.Marshal` inserts `\` then because they are _needed_, e.g. because `key` is a string containing double quotes. You are doing this all wrong. If key is already a JSON document as a string there is no reason to Mardshal it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you sending string as `key` in `func GetBytes(key interface{}) ([]byte, error)`. That's why you are seeing escape characters.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)


func f(key interface{}) {
    json, err := json.Marshal(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(json))
}

func main() {

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
    }

    f(data)

    json, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f(string(json))
}
```

Output:

```
{"A":1,"B":2}
"{\"A\":1,\"B\":2}"
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/iF1ckvZ9cQC

In that case, You can use `Unquote` to remove quote and escape character:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
)


func f(key interface{}) {
    json, err := json.Marshal(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(json))

    st, err := strconv.Unquote(string(json))
    fmt.Println(st)

}

func main() {

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
    }

    json, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f(string(json))
}
```

Output:

```
"{\"A\":1,\"B\":2}"
{"A":1,"B":2}
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/aoTEQtJslTs